# Has Force Lightning ever caused ventricular fibrillation in a victim?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

We have established that [Force Lightning produces an electric current in the victim's body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116110/31936) and [produces the same effects as an electric shock](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115696/31936). One of the [possible effects of electric shock includes ventricular fibrillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury#Ventricular_fibrillation), which [results in loss of consciousness and death within a matter of minutes unless treatment is provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventricular_fibrillation). Ventricular fibrillation can be triggered by a relatively low electric current (especially if the current passes through the heart), so even relatively weak Force Lightning could be lethal.

Has Force Lightning ever been depicted as causing ventricular fibrillation in a victim, either deliberately or accidentally? In other words, has a book ever described a Force Lightning attack as causing ventricular fibrillation or cardiac arrest, or has a visual depiction of a Force Lightning attack ever caused the victim to behave as someone with ventricular fibrillation? I am looking for examples from canon and/or Legends.

Comment: What makes you think authors analysed what electricity exactly  does to humans? I think there's plenty of reasons to think otherwise.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think most authors would consider the exact effect of electricity on humans, but it's possible a few authors did and depicted a character exploiting the possibility of electric shock incapacitating/killing a victim by ventricular fibrillation.

Comment: Um...Vader in Return of the Jedi?